# flow and formula field

Tags: visual-workflow, formula

I'm trying to populate a field on Case with the value from a field on Account using flow. However, the field on Account is a formula with Hyperlink so what i'm getting as a result on the case is this. Can anyone advise how to return a text - just name of the Top Level Account?

Many thanks
Ewa

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you have to use Flow and not just create another formula field on Case? Is the Case not associated with an Account?

Comment: @edralph It looks like OP is climbing up to the highest most Account in the hierarchy, which may not be reachable via a formula (Salesforce cuts you off at 5 relationship hops if I remember correctly). Ewa, you're probably assigning the wrong Account field. Using `Account.Name` should meet your needs for populating "Top Level Account New"

Comment: Yes, exactly that. it is 5 relationships already.

Comment: But i don't have Account.Name. I have and need the Top Account Level and there is no Account.Name available as it is a formula field.

Comment: I created another formula on Account that is showing the Top Level Account from old Top Level Account formula and now i can use that in my flow. Issue resolved. Thanks all.